# How should my docker-compose.yml file look to use HAProxy with Heroku and Docker?

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, haproxy

I was trying to follow [this article](https://pilot.co/blog/hosting-multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain/), but many things look different nowadays, so I ended up improvising. I'd like to simply connect my frontend with my backend, avoiding the CORS headache (although now I'm not sure which headache is the bigger one). Anyway, I defined my load balancer that way:

**app.json:**

```
{
  "name": "NeuroCore Load Balancer",
  "description": "A load balancer for NeuroCore"
}
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: sbin/haproxy -f haproxy.cfg
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM heroku/heroku:18

RUN mkdir -p /app/user  
WORKDIR /app/user

# Install HAProxy

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl1.0.0 libpcre3 --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV HAPROXY_MAJOR 1.5  
ENV HAPROXY_VERSION 1.5.14  
ENV HAPROXY_MD5 ad9d7262b96ba85a0f8c6acc6cb9edde

# see http://sources.debian.net/src/haproxy/1.5.8-1/debian/rules/ for some helpful navigation of the possible "make" arguments
RUN buildDeps='curl gcc libc6-dev libpcre3-dev libssl-dev make' \  
    && set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -SL "http://www.haproxy.org/download/${HAPROXY_MAJOR}/src/haproxy-${HAPROXY_VERSION}.tar.gz" -o haproxy.tar.gz \
    && echo "${HAPROXY_MD5}  haproxy.tar.gz" | md5sum -c \
    && mkdir -p /app/user/src/haproxy \
    && tar -xzf haproxy.tar.gz -C /app/user/src/haproxy --strip-components=1 \
    && rm haproxy.tar.gz \
    && make -C /app/user/src/haproxy \
        TARGET=linux2628 \
        USE_PCRE=1 PCREDIR= \
        USE_OPENSSL=1 \
        USE_ZLIB=1 \
    PREFIX=/app/user \
        all \
        install-bin \
    && rm -rf /app/user/src/haproxy \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps

COPY haproxy.cfg /app/user/haproxy.cfg
```

**haproxy.cfg:**

```
global  
    maxconn 256

defaults  
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http  
    bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT

    option forwardfor

    # Force SSL
    redirect scheme https code 301 if ! { hdr(x-forwarded-proto) https }

    # And all other requests to `example-com`.
    default_backend neurocore-backend

backend neurocore-backend  
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host neurocore.herokuapp.com
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]

    reqirep ^Host: Host:\ neurocore-backend.herokuapp.com    

    server backend neurocore-backend.herokuapp.com:443 ssl verify none
```

After running `docker-compose up web` I get:

> ```
> ERROR: 
>         Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
>         parent. Are you in the right directory?
>
>         Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
> ```

As far I can understand, this file should be generated by the `heroku docker:init` command, but it doesn't work nowadays. So, what should I do to make my app up and running?

Comment: This  blog post shows a docker-compose.yml for a similar configuration: https://www.learncloudnative.com/blog/2020-04-25-beginners-guide-to-gateways-proxies/